# True and False with Operators

Tags: c

me again ... Sorry for asking maybe a little bit stupid questions but i am a starter and i really want to learn coding .. So i got a problem to realize why those are always true ? Its something with the operators or again C  behavior is undefined. ?

```
   int x;
   int b;
   b = 1 < x < 10;
   printf("%d%d",b);
```

```
    char c = 'z';
    (c==' ') || (c='\t') || (c=='\n');
    printf("%c",c);
```

Why those are always true ? Its because of ASCII code or what ?

Comment: `c='\t'` - is this a typo? `printf("%d%d",b);` - you are using double `%d` with single argument. This is undefined behavior. `why those are always true ?` - can you be more specific? What "those" are always true? `x` in the first code snipped is uninitialized, do you ask if `x` is true?

Comment: You should enable all compiler warnings (with some compilers this is `-Wall`). The compiler will help you find bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Result of comparison of constant 10 with boolean expression is always true**

You can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) a table for the C Operator Precedences
it could be read like this:

```
b = ((1 < x) < 10);
```

being that in languages such as C, relational operators return the integers 0 or 1, where 0 stands for false and any non-zero value stands for true.

so the value stored in b is 1 (true)

Also:

you're not initializing `x`, it should have trash info (probably != false)

and in your second code, you're allocating instead of comparing, **(c='\t')** is this on purpose? That's the reason it's printing a 'tab'.

Answer (score 2):

In your first block of code, there are several problems:

1. `x` is uninitialized (you did not give it a value)
2. `1 < x < 10` is not valid C
3. your printf statement expects 2 integer values to accompany the "%d%d", but you are only passing 1

I think this is what you want:

```
int x = <some valid value>;
int b;
b = ((1 < x) && (x < 10)); // expression is true if x is between [2..9]
printf("%d",b);
```

This line

```
(c==' ') || (c='\t') || (c=='\n');
```

Should be

```
(c==' ') || (c=='\t') || (c=='\n');
```

Note the double equals when comparing to `\t` (the tab character). Otherwise, you wind up assigning a tab char to `c`.

Comment: Also the result of `(c==' ') || (c=='\t') || (c=='\n')` actually needs to be assigned to a variable so that its value can be printed.

Comment: ````C 
   int b;
   int x;
   scanf("%d",&x);
   b = 1 < x < 10;
   printf("%d%d",b);
````
This always give me 11 why is that ?

Comment: 1< x < 10 will be evaluated like (1<x) < 10 and will probably always be true (i.e. 1) because (1<x) will be 0 or 1 and both of these values are less then 10. I say probably because this might be undefined behavior in which case anything can happen.